# Starting a Wordpress site

Tags: static-website

What is the best way to start-up my site on wordpress?

I have a website made on Weebly, but that can no longer do what I need, so will be changing over to a WP site.

Do I need to install wordpress on my computer? Do I use wordpress.org to run my site or do I need to find a host?

Comment: What do you need to do that Weebly can't?

Comment: Advanced footers with widgets, custmoisable sidepannels. Lots and Lots.

Comment: Definitely use the answer below to get started, but since you are used to weebly with it's drag and drop functionality, you may want to search for drag and drop enabled themes

Comment: @Drai can you point towards a drag and drop?

Comment: Can't attest to either of these since I haven't used them, but i have used Weebly, so i know what you are used to.
http://headwaythemes.com/
http://www.pagelines.com/

Comment: I do use Drupal on a daily basis, so I am fairly confident in starting WP.

Comment: In that case, you're good to go! Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to run a Wordpress site you have to go for the self-hosted version and install Wordpress on a web server. It's not as hard as it sounds :)

**What you need**

- A web host (a simple shared host will do).
- PHP and MySQL must be available on the web host (very common).

  - PHP is a scripting language which Wordpress is built with.
  - MySQL is a database technology which handles all your posts and pages and other data.
- An FTP program to transfer files back and forth.
- A domain name.

You can download the latest copy of Wordpress from http://wordpress.org. Note the difference between Wordpress.org and Wordpress.com – the former is the hosted version where you sign up for an account and get a `name-of-blog.wordpress.com` web address. The latter is the site for the Wordpress project, where you find the software and other resources.

The Wordpress.org website is really helpful when it comes to installing Wordpress. It's famous for its "5 minute install". Your web host's support can help you setup the FTP client for transfering files to the server, which is essential in order to install Wordpress. *Note:* Some web hosts even offer a "One-click install" of Wordpress, where you manage the install on the server itself. I.e. you don't have to download the Wordpress files on your own computer and then transfer them yourself.

I recommend this page for you: http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress

Comment: What will I be FTPing? (if that is a word?)

Comment: The Wordpress core files. FTP (File Transfer Protocol) is essentially just file transfer. So: you need to **transfer** the files **to** your web host.

Comment: what files? I assume that when I want iamges etc, I will just use the upload function built into WP? is that incorrect?

Comment: Yes, but you have to upload the WP files in the first place, don't you? :) When you're **installing** it on the web server.

Comment: Right, I am looking for a one click install host so hadn't thought about that. Thanks